# Removing redundant variables from a query string

Tags: php, query-string

Is anyone aware of a way to remove redundant variables from a query string.

For example, reducing the below URL from this:

```
youtube.com/watch?v=123&feature=g-all&something=lalala
```

To the following:

```
youtube.com/watch?v=123
```

Alternatively, how could you compare two URLs with a different query string to check if they are the same page?

Comment: is `v` the only part of the query string you are interested in?

Comment: Not going to happen unless you define "redundant" well enough to please the compiler.

Comment: This was just an example. It could be anything such as 'index.php?id=123' or 'pagename.php?redundant=vaviable', etc.

Comment: If the 2 pages can be anything, what is the commonality that verifies the 2 pages are the same? Only the content on the page or something specific in the URL?

Comment: So ... it still remains ... *what does "redundant" mean in context*?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

php has built in functions for this; [parse_url](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php)() and [parse_str](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.parse-str.php)()

```
parse_str( 'watch?v=123&feature=g-all&something=lalala' );

// returns

array(3) {
  ["v"]=>
  string(3) "123"
  ["feature"]=>
  string(5) "g-all"
  ["something"]=>
  string(6) "lalala"
}
```

So, you can use both functions to extract the parameters you want without having to explode and guess the position of the parameters.

```
$url = parse_url( "youtube.com/watch?v=123&feature=g-all&something=lalala" );

parse_str( $url['query'], $query );

echo 'youtube.com/?v=' . $query["v"];  // youtube.com/?v=123
```

This should be better than exploding or even using regex.

Answer (score 3):

Try:

```
$url = "youtube.com/watch?v=123&feature=g-all&something=lalala";
echo $finalUrl = array_pop(array_reverse(explode("&", $url)));
```

Comment: You will want to specify a limit of 2 in the explode call.  Should improve performance (fewer array elements to merge).

Comment: Thanks for the reply! The only problem with this is this is that it relies on the first variable being the only one required to identify the page. For example, this would not work on a Google search results page. I guess it would be possible to compare the meta tags of the first URL with the second to make sure they are the same page?

Answer (score 2):

### Explode on the First Ampersand Encountered

```
<?php
$url = "youtube.com/watch?v=123&feature=g-all&something=lalala";
$final = explode("&", $url, 2);
echo $final[0];
?>
```

### Output

```
youtube.com/watch?v=123
```

Comment: third orgumnet of the function, is it required?

Comment: @punit Optional, as Josh stated, it is purely a performance enhancement.